# VSCode No Output after Running

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am running into an issue running my code in vscode, I know the code is not the issue because it was working fine before I restarted the application. It shows the control box, but the code does not run.

[Here is a GIF of what is happening.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdMiv.gif)

I have:

- Uninstalled and re-installed
- Deleted all VSCode AppData folders
- Re-installed extensions

however nothing has worked.

Comment: is your java executable in your path environment variable?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Hi! I added java to the PATH but that didn't work, so I uninstalled everything java related and re-installed Java and the JDK and allowed it to add to the PATH however the same issue is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by instead of just opening the .java file alone, I selected to option to "Open a Folder" where my project was located inside, and loaded my project that way - this solved my issue.

Comment: You may accept your answer to mark this question as resolved.